# Why function does not receive inputted JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-boilerplate

I've got a custom jQuery plugin I'm working on with a bit of issue with JSON.

I'm using the [jQuery plugin boilerplate](https://jqueryboilerplate.com/) to create this and am setting the default properties at the top like so:

```
// Create the defaults once
var pluginName = "customHighlight",
        defaults = {
            actions: [{"test_action":"Test action"}],
            position: "left"
};
```

The issue is that when I try to set my own properties on initiation of the plugin like so:

```
$('div,p').customHighlight({
     actions: [{"1_action":"1 action"}]
});
```

I get nothing coming through. Am I making a school boy error that I haven't caught here?

Comment: You need to include the code where you combine what's been passed in with the defaults, and perhaps how you're determining what you've been passed.

Comment: There's no JSON there. `actions` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "nothing coming through". It's entirely possible that you're making a mistake in your implementation of the boilerplate, and you haven't shown any of the relevant code, so we can't point that out for you, but there is one general design flaw in your setup.

If you're using the boilerplate correctly, your plugin's `settings` property will look like this:

```
{
    actions: [{"1_action":"1 action"}],
    position: "left"
}
```

I assume you were expecting `actions` to be an array with two objects. This outcome is because you are specifying a value for `actions`, and so `$.extend` which is being used in `Plugin.prototype.init` doesn't use the default value.

You could solve this by changing this line in `init`:

```
this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
```

To this:

```
this.settings = $.extend( true, {}, defaults, options );
                      //  ^ "deep" param
```

Setting [`deep`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) indicates that `$.extend` should be applied recursively. But this doesn't work for arrays, so you also need to make sure `actions` is an object:

```
var pluginName = "customHighlight",
        defaults = {
            actions: {"test_action":"Test action"},
            position: "left"
};
```

Now, calling `customHighlight` like this:

```
$('div,p').customHighlight({
     actions: {"1_action":"1 action"}
});
```

Would result in a `settings` object that looks like this:

```
{
    actions: {
       "test_action": "Test action"
       "1_action": "1 action"
    },
    position: "left"
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cob40fdt/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. Luckily I realised my error was just in not really knowing how jQuery boilerplate really works! I've typed my answer/thought-process below.

Comment: @Tapha: Glad your issue is solved. You may still want to note that the `actions` array will be overwritten and not appended to, unless you manually intervene to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the settings object is what I needed to retrieve, instead of the defaults object that I was retrieving in my code. I didn't provide enough info here for a successful answer to be given so apologies. But the issue is now resolved.

Cheers